# How to model predict on Tensorflow model that has feature columns?

Tags: tensorflow, feature-engineering, predict

So far all the coding examples using feature columns do not have examples of how to format their `model.predict(...)`.  I tried using raw string and also putting them into np.arrays.  I am very new so please be gentle :).

Here is the official page, as you can see, no predict example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns

Comment: Please explain a bit more on your need

Answer (score 0):

You can find prediction examples in the next tutorial: [Classify structured data using Keras Preprocessing Layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers).

The list of tutorials in the series is in the bottom left part:

[image]

Specifically, the prediction examples are in the "Inference on new data" section (the last one in the tutorial).

Comment: Thank you for answering this.  I am currently not working on these projects, so it will take me awhile to validate this answer.